# How to Plot an exponential distribution of spike times over a histogram of them, in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, exponential-distribution

So my question follows the development after my last one. I have been trying to work on getting the spike times as a rastor plot for a spike train. I took a firing rate of 100 and got spike train for 20 trials: The code for that is:

```
fr = 100
dt = 1/1000 #dt in milisecond
duration = 2 #no of duration in s
nBins = 2000 #SpikeTrain
nTrials = 20 #NumberOfSimulations
MyPoissonSpikeTrain = function(p, fr= 100) {
  p = runif(nBins)
  q = ifelse(p < fr*dt, 1, 0)
  return(q)
}

set.seed(1)
SpikeMat <- t(replicate(nTrials, MyPoissonSpikeTrain()))

plot(x=-1,y=-1, xlab="time (s)", ylab="Trial",
main="Spike trains",
ylim=c(0.5, nTrials+1), xlim=c(0, duration))
for (i in 1: nTrials)
{
  clip(x1 = 0, x2= duration, y1= (i-0.2), y2= (i+0.4))
  abline(h=i, lwd= 1/4)
  abline(v= dt*which( SpikeMat[i,]== 1))
}
```

This gives the result: 
[image: Spike Trains]

After all this was done, my next task was to get a vector of Inter-Spike intervals and get a histogram of them. Because the distribution of ISIs follows the exponential distribution, if I plot the exponential distribution of ISIs with the same data, it will match the curve made by the height of the histograms. 
So to get the interspike timings first, I used:

```
spike_times <- c(dt*which( SpikeMat[i, ]==1))
```

Then to get a vector for interspike intervals and their histogram, I used the following command line,

```
ISI <- diff(spike_times)
hist(ISI, density= 10, col= 'blue', xlab='ISI(ms)', ylab='number of occurences')
```

and it gave me this plot:

[image: HistogramsofISIs]

Now, What I want is to plot the exponential distributions within the histograms that justifies the exponential distribution nature of the inter spike intervals. I am confused about what parameters to use and which rate to use. If somebody has worked with Interspike interval plotting, please help. And I am sorry if my data seems incomplete, please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fellow researcher just told me a few simple lines of code:

```
x <- seq(0, 0.05, length=1000)
y <- dexp(x, rate=100)
lines(x,y)
```

which gave me this:
[image: HistogramWithExpoDis]